# How to translate webpage from google translate dropdown using custom button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to translate my webpage only for Hindi Language by clicking a custom button.
When I clicked this button. Select Option value change only not translating the webpage.
Can some one help me to fix this issue?

http://jsfiddle.net/n19xyzeo/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title> Google Translater for Website </title> 
</head> 
<body>
  <h2>Your Web Page</h2>
  <p>Click on the dropdown button to translate.</p>
  <p>Translate this page:</p>

  <div id="google_translate_element"></div>

// page should be translate after click on this button
  <button type="button" id="hindi">T into Hindi</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
    }
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js"></script>
  <p class="notranslate"> This Paragraph will remain same because it is using notranslate class.</p>

  <p class="translate"> This Paragraph will change because it is using translate class. </p> 

  <script>
    $('#hindi').on('click', function(){

      $('select.goog-te-combo')
      .val('hi')
      .trigger('change');
    })

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the `.goog-te-combo` select element?

Comment: Google Translate generates all codes automatically on window load